# how to add the script to the wordpress page

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I am trying to create the appear and disappear effect as found on this page http://dante.swiftideas.net/developer-documentation , there are three scripts getting fired 
jquery-1.9.1.js, jquery-ui.js and then there is a third script without a name. So how to add the third script to a specific wordpress page?

Comment: You can add that in to the `header.php` or in `footer.php` with `<script>` tag.

Comment: I want to add that to a specific wordpress page and also to add it I have to have a name for the script.

Comment: Every wordpress page have `header.php` and `footer.php`.So your **JS** will be called.

Comment: @Rohil_PHPBeginner...the correct way to do this is via **functions.php**

Comment: Use Google more! This has been covered A LOT. One of many articles: http://code.tutsplus.com/articles/the-complete-guide-to-proper-javascript-usage-with-wordpress--wp-32172 Also note, that adding the scripts to `header.php` is not the way to go, you should always use `wp_enqueue_script` funtion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use the [wp_enqueue_script()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script) function inside your theme's functions.php - it's meant to be used for this purpose.
If you only want this script to load on a single specific page, then you can wrap the `wp_enqueue_script` function with a conditional to check if it's that specific page (by the page's ID in wordpress):

```
if (is_page(123)) {
    function theme_name_scripts() {
        wp_enqueue_script( 'script-name', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/example.js', array(), '1.0.0', true ); }
    }
    add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_name_scripts' );
}
```